# ssl connection fails with wget, suceeds in browsers

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https

I have a server running Apache 2.4 with various virtual hosts that provide https:// connections.

These all are set up seemingly correctly and work fine in all browsers.

However one virtual host fails to be verified when using wget. Unfortunately I need wget to work for some server side programming.

```
ERROR: cannot verify myvirtualhost.ca's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
```

On further investigation, debugging with this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect myvirtualhost.ca:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
```

It seems that the reason the verification fails, is because another one of the server's certificates is getting involved somehow.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = defaultdomain.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = defaultdomain.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = defaultdomain.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

So the CN relates to another one of the virtual hosts on the server (the "defaultdomain.com" that the server falls back to).

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server has multiple HTTPS sites on one IP address, you must use SNI to differentiate between each one.

To get `openssl s_client` to work with SNI you need to add the `-servername <your fqdn>` argument:

```
openssl s_client -connect myvirtualhost.ca:443 -servername myvirtualhost.ca -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
```

Comment: Ah right - so in other words that isn't something I can fix server side ... it's a client configuration problem? In this case the client is a software on the server itself which is using curl or wget (or similar) to get asynchronous data in lieu of something sensible like an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to get wget working, use the flag "--no-check-certificate", could be insecure but if you need wget working asap, you can use it.

> wget --no-check-certificate ...